# Impala vs Spark performance for ad hoc queries

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, database-design, apache-spark-sql, impala

I'm interested only in query performance reasons and architectural differences behind them. All answers I've seen before were outdated or hadn't provide me with enough context of WHY Impala is better for ad hoc queries.

From 3 considerations below only the 2nd point explain why Impala is faster on bigger datasets. *Could you please contribute to the following statements?*

1. Impala doesn't miss time for query pre-initialization, means impalad daemons are always running & ready. In other hand, [Spark Job Server provide persistent context](https://objectpartners.com/2017/03/07/spark-job-server-for-persistent-contexts-and-low-latency-jobs/) for the same purposes.
2. Impala is in-memory and can spill data on disk, with performance penalty, when data doesn't have enough RAM. The same is true for Spark. The main difference is that Spark is written on Scala and have JVM limitations, so workers bigger than 32 GB aren't recommended (because of GC). In turn, ***[wrong, see UPD]***  <s>Impala is implemented on C++</s>, and has [high hardware requirements](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_prereqs.html): 128-256+ GBs of RAM recommended. <s>This is very significant, but should benefit Impala only on datasets that requires 32-64+ GBs of RAM.</s>
3. Impala is integrated with Hadoop infrastructure. AFAIK the main reason to use Impala over another in-memory DWHs is the ability to run over Hadoop data formats without exporting data from Hadoop. Means Impala usually use the same storage/data/partitioning/bucketing as Spark can use, and do not achieve any extra benefit from data structure comparing to Spark. Am I right?

P.S. Is Impala faster than Spark in 2019? Have you seen any performance benchmarks?

### UPD:

Questions update:

I. *Why Impala recommends 128+ GBs RAM? What is an implementation language of each Impala's component?* Docs say that "Impala daemons run on every node in the cluster, and each daemon is capable of acting as the query planner, the query coordinator, and a query execution engine.". If `impalad` is Java, than what parts are written on C++? Is there smth between impalad & columnar data? Are 256 GBs RAM required for impalad or some other component?

II. *Impala loose all in-memory performance benefits when it comes to cluster shuffles (JOINs), right? Does Impala have any mechanics to boost JOIN performance compared to Spark?*

III. Impala use Multi-Level Service Tree (smth like Dremel Engine see "Execution model" [here](https://panoply.io/data-warehouse-guide/bigquery-architecture/)) vs Spark's Directed Acyclic Graph. *What does actually MLST vs DAG mean in terms of ad hoc query performance? Or it's a better fit for multi-user environment?*

Comment: Impala **backend** is written in C++, while frontend (both impalad and catalogd) components are Java. See https://github.com/apache/impala.

Comment: @mazaneicha sorry, can't find any mention of which component is implemented on Java vs C++. Pls take a look at UPD section of my question

Comment: I think impalad should be written on C++, because what else could be written on C++ if not a part that do direct IO

Comment: Both impalad and catalogd have frontend (fe) and backend (be) components to them -- very roughly, front-ends are the comms/protocol layer implemented in Java, and back-ends are the "brain"/processing layer implemented in cc. statestored is purely cc afaik. You can find all the details in the git repo I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @mazaneicha thanks, will take a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I don't think comparison of a general purpose distributed computing framework and distributed DBMS (SQL engine) has much meaning. But if we would still like to compare a single query execution in *single-user* mode (?!), then the biggest difference IMO would be what you've already mentioned -- Impala query coordinators have everything (table metadata from Hive MetaStore + block locations from NameNode) cached in memory, while Spark will need time to extract this data in order to perform query planning.

Second biggie would probably be shuffle implementation, with Spark writing temp files to disk at stage boundaries against Impala trying to keep everything in-memory. Leading to a radical difference in resilience - while Spark can recover from losing an executor and move on by recomputing missing blocks, Impala will fail the entire query after a single *impalad* daemon crash.

Less significant performance-wise (since it typically takes much less time compared to everything else) but architecturally important is work distribution mechanism -- compiled whole stage codegens sent to the workers in Spark vs. declarative query fragments communicated to daemons in Impala.

As far as specific query optimization techniques (query vectorization, dynamic partition pruning, cost-based optimization) -- they could be on par today or will be in the near future.

Comment: first of all, thank you for such a good answer! I want to ask you about two more clarifications. 1) Does Spark writing some state-related metadata to temp files? AFAIK Spark shouldn't write any part of dataset to disk without excplicit persist command. I can't find documentation describing content of that temp files. 2) Could you please also add details to your answer about how Impala manage multiple users simultaneously and why it's inappropriate to compare Spark and Impala. Thank you!

Comment: At stage boundary, shuffle blocks are written to/read from local file system by executors. Also worth to mention external shuffle service, which is a prereq if you run Spark in cluster mode with dynamic allocation. Please check Spark docs for more details https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#graceful-decommission-of-executors. For Impala architecture overview refer to https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_components.html#intro_components.

Comment: thank you for details! I desided that it may be worth to significantly update the current question instead of creating a few inferior questions. In turn I will create a bounty for it tomorrow. Pls take a look at UPD section

Comment: your update basically changes the modality of the whole question. Even title is now seems non-descriptive. Maybe you would reconsider and split this topic into multiple separate questions?

Comment: okey, than I approve the current answer and will create a new